# Detect which application is playing sound / video

Tags: audio, video, background-process

I sometimes have applications that keep playing video and/or sound when in the background. These applications do not always show up in the notification area on my Samsung S8+ - but I guess this is not device related.

Is there anyway of detecting which application it is? Currently I'm having to guess which application to shut down. E.g. the Dutch NOS news app does this: it suddenly replays video after a while with sound. Needless to say, this can be really annoying.

Either programming or Android UI solutions welcome.

Comment: When it starts playing again, check your active applications (not recent apps) it might show there what app is active now